# How can you solve this problem quickly by binomial theorem? Is there another way?

Tags: algorithm

The problem I'm trying to solve is finding the value of the formula below when the values `l, r, k` are given `M` times.

```
 r
 Σ  [ Ai × (i-l+1)^k ]
i=l
```

The ranges are: `1 ≤ l ≤ r ≤ N`, `0 ≤ k ≤ 10`, `1 ≤ N, M ≤ 10 ^ 5`.

I would like to know how to solve this problem when the time limit is 2 seconds.

Comment: Which programming language? And what is your current implementation in that language? And how long does that implementation take currently?

Comment: It is not clear what indices and values you sum over.

Comment: The sequence A is given as input, i is the index of A, and l is the interval.

Comment: Why do you think that the binomial theorem would help here?

Comment: Initially, a sequence A of length N is input, followed by M inputs in the form "l r k". This is the value of the above equation.

Comment: The range of Σ is l ≤ i ≤ r.

Comment: You can use a DP approach where you calculate 11 arrays( for k = 0...10), with the prefix sum for that k. Then just subtract and return. For example for k=0, dp[i] would just be the sum of A[0...i]. Then for l, r you return dp[r] - dp[l-1].

Comment: Is it possible to calculate Ai * (i - l + 1) ^ k by DP equation?

Answer (score 2):

Re-writing the formula for clarity:

[image]

Define and compute a *lookup table* `B` as below:

[image]

Expand the `(i - l + 1)^k` term using the Binomial theorem, where `(k, j)` is the [Binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient):

[image]

So this look-up table can be used to calculate each value of `S(l, r, k)` in just **`O(k)`** time complexity. Much better than **`O(r - l) = O(N)`** of the naive algorithm!

Rewrite the formula above slightly by substituting an index, to make summation a little easier:

[image]

I will provide code if you request, but I strongly suggest that you try to implement this yourself first.